# In bUnit how do I verify an element does not exist

Tags: bunit

I have the following code:

```
var li = renderedComponent.Find("li.validation-message");
Assert.Null(li);
```

The `Find()` call is throwing an exception instead of returning null. And `HasComponent<>()` needs a type. It's not clear what type to put in that.

Comment: Check FindAll is empty?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm kicking myself for not thinking of something so obvious. Thanks you. Also, if you make that an answer, I'm happy to accept it.